# How do I book a seat reservation on ICE International, when I already have the ticket?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

I have a ticket London-Brussels-Frankfurt, booked via a travel agent from DB Vertrieb GmbH.  The ticket comes with a seat reservation London-Brussels (EST 9140), but not Brussels-Frankfurt (ICE19).  On Bahn.de, I choose the option "Nur Sitzplatz (kein Ticket)", then search for the relevant train,  The train is listed, after I click on "Zur Reservierung" it asks for my age.  After entering my age and "Aktualisieren", I'm stuck:

[image: Screenshot from Bahn.de]

How do I proceed from here?  I need only a one-way ticket.  Usually there would be a purchase option in the column *Preis für alle Reisenden*, or a notification that this ticket cannot be booked.  For the ICE, it's just blank.

How can I reserve a seat?

---

In the end, my employer's travel agent booked a seat at my request.  I don't know if they did so through the website or by phone.

Comment: I tried to reserve a seat for your connection right now, and to me it seems that currently there is a problem with the website, because sometimes the button to proceed with the reservation appears for me and sometimes unfortunately not. However I was not able to find a workflow which works everytime, so just some hints you maybe like to try: Disable a adblocker (or similar programs), jump between the different steps of booking back and forth or try booking using a incognito browser window. Good luck with that, because usually that should work.

Comment: Did you end up reserving the seat?

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes.  See edit.

Answer (score 6):

The above method is correct and it seems to be working ok now. (Incidentally, there is also an English version of the site where you can book 'Seat Only' reservations if this is easier to follow). Normally the reservations are unavailable at short notice before departure, or for fully booked and sometimes multiple-operator routes where DB cannot access the seat reservation system.

You can also buy reservations-only from DB self service ticket machines at most German railway stations on the day. (I am not sure about stations in Brussels though.)